# CSS square with dynamic height

Tags: css

I need to make a `div` square. The height of the `div` is dynamically changing and I want the width to be equal to the height. I have seen a lot of solutions to set the *height* to be equal to the *width* (with `padding-bottom` on pseudo-elements), but I need it the other way arround. Is this possible with pure CSS?

Comment: CSS cannot do this, javascritp would be required to work in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No .... well, there is this trick, where one use a hidden image

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 170px;
  background: red;
}
div img {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
</div>
```

---

Updated

And here is a script version, that also keep it within the width

Stack snippet

```js
(function (d,t) {
  window.addEventListener("resize", throttler, false);
  window.addEventListener("load", throttler(), false);  /*  run once on load to init  */
  
  function throttler() {
    if ( !t ) {
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        t = null;
        keepSquared(d.querySelector('.container'),
                    d.querySelector('.squared'));
       }, 66);
    }
  }
  function keepSquared(co,el) {
    var s = window.getComputedStyle(co, null);
    var m = Math.min(
      parseFloat(s.getPropertyValue("width")),
      parseFloat(s.getPropertyValue("height")));
    el.style.cssText = 
      'width: ' + m + 'px; height: ' + m + 'px;';
  }
})(document,null);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.squared {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="squared">
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Since [`resize` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) can fire at a high rate, the throttler is used to reduced the rate so the handler doesn't execute expensive operations such as DOM modifications too often.*

Comment: I'll give this a try! Thanks.

Comment: well, this is not dynamic and how do you insert content here ? another fake example but with content inserted http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PbrreM still not efficient cause won'nt grow according to content

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks for your comment. The hidden image's sole purpose is to keep its parent a square, which was the question. For any other content an absolute div will be needed, as a wrapper. I also wrote "No", as in it can't be done unless the mentioned down sides is of no concern. ... With that, no matter the height given the div, it will always be a square, which again is how I interpret the question

Comment: I agree, i guess i do not see the purpose of the question anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reposting my answer here, since the question is slightly different:

The simplest way of getting proper squares is using the [**CSS container queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_containment/Container_queries). These let you say "this element is a container" and then "use the width/height of the container".

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  container-type: size;
}

.square {
  width: 100cqmin;
  height: 100cqmin;
  
  background: blue; /* for demo purposes */
}
```

```html
<!-- Resizable container for demo -->
<div style="border: 1px solid black; resize: both; height: 80px; width: 300px; overflow: auto; ">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square">
      My beautiful content is right here: Lorem ipsum
      <br>
      blabla
      <br>
      cats are cute
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```